# Proof involving the sup. and inf. of a set mapped onto $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. Prove that

$\sup \{{ f(x)  | \,x \in [a,b]\} - \inf \{f(x)  | \, x \in [a,b] }\} = \sup \{|f(x) - f(y)|  \text{ such that  } x \in [a,b] \text{ and } y \in [a,b]\}$

Apologize for poor formatting, I can't get brackets to show up to indicate sets within the formula.

Also, I have no idea whatsoever how the relationship between the sup/inf (both with respect to f(x)) relate to the sup f(y).

Answer (score 1):

Forget about $f$. It's all about a nonempty set $S\subset{\mathbb R}$. Let 
$$d:=\sup\nolimits_{u,v\in S}|v-u|\leq\infty$$ be the diameter of $S$. We have to prove that
$$\sup S-\inf S=d\ .$$
When $S$ is unbounded this is trivially true. Therefore we may assume that $S$ is bounded.

Since for all $u$, $v\in S$ we have
$$|v-u|=\max\{u,v\}-\min\{u,v\}\leq \sup S-\inf S$$
we can conclude that $d\leq\sup S-\inf S$.

Conversely, take an $u\in S$. Then for all $v\in S$ we have $v-u\leq|v-u|\leq d$, and therefore
$$v\leq d+u\qquad\forall v\in S\ .$$
This says that $d+u$ is an upper bound for $S$, so $\sup S\leq d+u$, which is equivalent with
$$u\geq \sup S-d\ ,$$
and this is true for all $u\in S$. It follows that $\inf S\geq \sup S-d$, or
$\sup S-\inf S\leq d$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I = [a,b]$. Clearly $\sup f(I) \ge \inf f(I)$ and $\sup f(I) \ge f(x) \ge \inf f(I)$ for all $x \in I$. Similarly, $-\sup f(I) \le -f(y) \le -\inf f(I)$ for all $y \in I$.

Hence
$\sup f(I)-\inf f(I) \ge f(x)-f(y) \ge \inf f(I)-\sup f(I)$ for all $x,y \in I$,
or, in other words, $\sup f(I)-\inf f(I) \ge |f(x)-f(y)|$ for all $x,y \in I$. It follows that $\sup f(I)-\inf f(I) \ge \sup_{x,y \in I}|f(x)-f(y)|$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, then there exists some $x',y' \in I$ such that $f(x') > \sup f(I) -\epsilon$, $f(y') < \inf f(I) + \epsilon$. Hence $f(x')-f(y') > \sup f(I)-\inf f(I) -2 \epsilon$. Hence 
$\sup_{x,y \in I}|f(x)-f(y)| \ge \sup_{x,y \in I}f(x)-f(y) \ge \sup f(I)-\inf f(I) -2 \epsilon$. Since this golds for all $\epsilon>0$, we have 
$\sup_{x,y \in I}|f(x)-f(y)| \ge \sup f(I)-\inf f(I)$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be done by proving inequality in both directions. Take an arbitrary member from the set on the right.  Suppose, without loss of generality that $f(x)\leq f(y)$.  Then $|f(x)-f(y)| = f(y) - f(x) \leq \sup_{[a,b]} f(x) - f(x) \leq \sup_{[a,b]} f(x) -\inf_{[a,b]} f(x).  Therefore $\sup_{[a,b]^2} |f(x)-f(y)| \leq \sup_{[a,b]} f(x) -\inf_{[a,b]} f(x)$.

To prove the other direction, let $\epsilon>0$ and show $\sup_{[a,b]} f(x) -\inf_{[a,b]} f(x) \leq \epsilon + \sup_{[a,b]^2} |f(x)-f(y)|$ by choosing $(x,y) \in [a,b] \times [a,b]$ such that $f(x) \in (\sup_{[a,b]} f(x)-\epsilon/2, \sup_{[a,b]} f(x))$, and doing similarly for $y$ with $\inf$. You're just about there.